# Is it possible to read firewall rules in Windows from Python?

Tags: python, windows, windows-firewall

I am making an auditing type tool and I want to pull the firewall rules of the computer. I am using Python and I can only find sources on how to add rules to the firewall, but not read them. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

i'm not using python that's why i can't help you with coding, but as everything in windows, firewall rules are storing in registry too, firewall rules are storing under;

```
HKLM\System\CurrentlControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules.
```

I believe if you can read windows registry with python,then you can read the rules.

Detailed source : [https://schatzforensic.com/insideout/2014/12/was-the-firewall-blocking-traffic-identifying-active-firewall-rules-using-registry-analysis/#:~:text=The%20firewall%20rules%20are%20stored,%5CParameters%5CFirewallPolicy%5CFirewallRules.](https://schatzforensic.com/insideout/2014/12/was-the-firewall-blocking-traffic-identifying-active-firewall-rules-using-registry-analysis/#:%7E:text=The%20firewall%20rules%20are%20stored,%5CParameters%5CFirewallPolicy%5CFirewallRules.)

Comment: The registry is not a public programming interface.

Comment: i didn't say it is